# Simplest possible Joomla Download Manager

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I want to create a Joomla page where my users can download view files (pdf's, excel sheet's, ...).

There will be around 20 Files available. The files are split up into 4 categories.

I want to show all files on a single page. The categories should be shown as a header.

My page is available in 3 languages. I do have different files for every language. I do only want to show the files matching the specific language.

The download MUST be a one-click-experience.

The whole page has to be styled according to a predefined design.

What is the best way to archive this? Is there any simple extension for that? Do I have to create my own? Should I use a Page-Builder?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Attachments pluggin](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/attachments/) I think it's the best free solution out there. Easy to use and allows to access files based on access level of certain user. However to obtain functionality you need I'd recommend creating access groups based on language.